# Correct terminology for a "matrix of array" or a "matrix of vectors"

Tags: matrices, vectors

What is the correct terminology to name the following matrix, that contains arrays as elements?

I would call it as a **matrix of arrays** or a **matrix of vectors**, but I am not sure. Other names?

Just to add some further information:

- $a_{ijk}=f_k(P_i,Q_j)$, i.e. the elements of the matrix $A$ are real numbers that result from $k=1,...,K$ different functions that act on a pair of probability distributions, $P_i$ and $Q_j$.
- $(a_{ijk})_{i\ne j}\ge0$, i.e. non-negative off-diagonal elements
- $a_{iik}=a_{jjk}=0$, i.e. diagonal elements equal to zero
- $a_{ijk}=a_{jik}$, i.e. symmetry between $i$ and $j$ elements, for each $k$-function

[image]

Just for information, this is the generating Latex code:

```
A=(a_{ijk})=
\left| 
\begin{array}{c@{}c@{}c}
  \left|\begin{array}{c}
         0 \\
         0 \\
         0 \\
         \vdots \\
         0 \\
  \end{array}\right|
  &  \left|\begin{array}{c}
         a_{121} \\
         a_{122} \\
         a_{123} \\
         \vdots \\
         a_{12K} \\
  \end{array}\right|  
  &  \left|\begin{array}{c}
         a_{131} \\
         a_{132} \\
         a_{133} \\
         \vdots \\
         a_{13K} \\
  \end{array}\right|\\
  \left|\begin{array}{c}
         a_{211} \\
         a_{212} \\
         a_{213} \\
         \vdots \\
         a_{21K} \\
  \end{array}\right| 
  & 
  \left|\begin{array}{c}
         0 \\
         0 \\
         0 \\
         \vdots \\
         0 \\
  \end{array}\right|
  &  \left|\begin{array}{c}
         a_{231} \\
         a_{232} \\
         a_{233} \\
         \vdots \\
         a_{23K} \\
  \end{array}\right|\\
  \left|\begin{array}{c}
         a_{311} \\
         a_{312} \\
         a_{313} \\
         \vdots \\
         a_{31K} \\
  \end{array}\right|  
  &  \left|\begin{array}{c}
         a_{321} \\
         a_{322} \\
         a_{323} \\
         \vdots \\
         a_{32K} \\
  \end{array}\right|
  & 
  \left|\begin{array}{c}
         0 \\
         0 \\
         0 \\
         \vdots \\
         0 \\
  \end{array}\right|
  \\ 
\end{array}\right|
```

Comment: I would say that it kind of depends on the application. One might as well call this matrix just a matrix of real (I guess) numbers. In that case it would be a $\mathbb{R} ^{3K \times 3}$ Matrix. However it might make sense to interpret it as a Matrix of vectors since it resembles the structure you are describing better. Array would seem kind of unusual to me in a mathematical context but that's just my opinion.

Comment: thanks a lot @RaoulLuqué! :-) Yes, the elements of the matrix are real numbers

Comment: You could always store this data in a tensor (by which I mean simply a multidimensional array).

Comment: Thanks @littleO..... However, I do not know how to represent/display it... also, would it make sense? I am full of doubts :-)

Comment: In my opinion it's a $3$-dimensional array, until it's given transformational properties viz. contravariant and covariant indices whence it becomes a tensor

Comment: Yeah, in the worlds of applied math and machine learning the word “tensor” is often used to mean simply “multidimensional array of numbers” whereas in math the word “tensor” means something more complicated. (A mathematician’s tensor could be described by a multidimensional array, kind of like how a linear transformation can be described by a matrix.) It’s probably too late to stop the machine learning definition of “tensor”.

Comment: @limone you can display it as multiple 2-dimensional arrays, written as $A_{i1k}$, $A_{i2k}$, $A_{i3k}$ (or you can choose any index to traverse over but choose the smallest dimension to traverse over for the sake of readability). For a higher dimensional array you can do the same but with exponentially the number of 2D arrays to write.

Comment: @RaoulLuqué.... I forgot something small... you wrote $\mathbb{R}^{3K\times3}$....but, what if I write $\mathbb{R}^{3K} \times \mathbb{R}^{3}$?

Comment: @littleO, thanks... In the machine learning world, yes, people would easily call my object a tensor, but just referring to a multidimensional array as mere data storage... On the other side, a math tensor would have some properties, as invariance under a change of basis...

Comment: @Localth, thanks.... in order to give transformational properties, I should introduce or define the (canonical) basis vectors. Then, I would need to show the tensor invariance under a change of basis, a tensorial product, etc... but in my case, I am not able to see all these "elements" and properties in my matrix-like object... In addition, since all my elements are scalars resulting from functions acting over probability distributions, how can I introduce or define a basis vector? or a tensorial products? or other...?